# C code compilation problems in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to compile C programs in VS2010 Professional using cl.exe (64bit command line). Getting strange errors in VS2010 or VS2008. Same Code compiles & runs in GNU gcc without a problem (Cygwin). Any ideas? Can't go any further with the real thing until I understand the problem here. Thanks!

filename: testC.c

> cl.exe testC.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef double Td;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      FILE *fp;
      if ( (fp=fopen("junk_out.txt","w")) == NULL ){
                printf("Cannot open file.\n");
                exit(1);
      }
      fprintf(fp,"%f \n",3.1420);
      fclose(fp);
      Td x=3.14;
      Td *a;
      a = &x;
      printf("%f \n",a);
      printf("%f \n",x);
      printf("%f \n",*a);

      return 0;
   }
```

Here is the output:

```
      testC.c(18): error C2275: 'Td' : illegal use of this type as an expression
      testC.c(5) : see declaration of 'Td'
      testC.c(18): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'x'
      testC.c(18): error C2065: 'x' : undeclared identifier
      testC.c(18): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
      testC.c(19): error C2275: 'Td' : illegal use of this type as an expression
      testC.c(5) : see declaration of 'Td'
      testC.c(19): error C2065: 'a' : undeclared identifier
      testC.c(21): error C2065: 'a' : undeclared identifier
      testC.c(21): error C2065: 'x' : undeclared identifier
      testC.c(21): warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'int *'
      testC.c(22): error C2065: 'a' : undeclared identifier
      testC.c(23): error C2065: 'x' : undeclared identifier
      testC.c(24): error C2065: 'a' : undeclared identifier
      testC.c(24): error C2100: illegal indirection
```

Comment: Please revise your title so it will be useful to future visitors. Also, please describe what you have already tried. Is the problem that you don't understand what the error message means? Focus on the first error. The rest are usually just cascade errors.

Comment: C89 rules required, declarations must appear before any statements.  Move x and a to the top of the function body.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define every variable at the top of a function if you compile your code with the C compiler from VS2010.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef double Td;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    Td x;
    Td *a;
    if ( (fp=fopen("junk_out.txt","w")) == NULL )
    {
            printf("Cannot open file.\n");
            exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(fp,"%f \n",3.1420);
    fclose(fp);
    x=3.14;
    a = &x;
    printf("%f \n",a);
    printf("%f \n",x);
    printf("%f \n",*a);

    return 0;
}
```

In C++ you can define everywhere you want.

Comment: That's true of < C99 but not in general.

Comment: But in VS2010 it is necessary.

Comment: Thank you! I moved the variable definitions on the top and it worked.

Comment: @hamon I'll admit I'm no expert in VS, but are you saying VS2010 doesn't support C99? Also, I would suggest you edit your post to say "in VC2010" or "in C89 which is what VC2010 supports".